# Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. Choices are: categoria, categoria_id, detalle_compra,

Tags: ajax, django

No entiendo lo que estoy haciendo mal. Estoy tratando de hacer un autocomplete con los datos de la tabla Producto, no se cual sea el motivo ya que hago mencion del nombre del producto pero lo toa como "name". Lo he hecho pero sigo recibiendo este error:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. Choices are: categoria, categoria_id, detalle_compra, ...
```

¿Alguna idea?

```
class Producto(models.Model):
    id_producto = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    def toJSON(self):
        item = model_to_dict(self)
        return item
        
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Producto'
```

Views

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {}
        try:
            action = request.POST['action']
            if action == 'autocomplete':
                productos = Producto.objects.filter(name__icontains=request.POST['term'])
                for i in productos:
                    data = []
                    item = i.toJSON()
                    item['value'] = i.nombre
                    data.append(item)
            else:
```

JS

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: window.location.pathname,
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: {
                                'action': 'autocomplete',
                                'term': request.term
                            },
                            dataType: 'json',
                        }).done(function (data) {
                            response(data);
                        }).fail(function (data) {
                            alert("Error"); 
                        }).always(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                           
                        })
                    },
```

He verificado que no sea "name" sin embargo en ninguno de los archivos he cometido esa equivacion. Espero puedan ayudarme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola espero te encuentres bien, te explico que sucede, tienes una linea que pone:

```
productos = Producto.objects.filter(name__icontains=request.POST['term'])
```

Ahí le estas indicando que filtre el queryset con el campo name y el icontains indica que la coincidencia no distinga entre mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Y si observas tu modelo Producto no tienes ningún campo name, por eso te sale el error.

Si tuvieras un campo nombre en tu modelo Producto y quisieras aplicar el filtro ahí, te quedaría:

```
productos = Producto.objects.filter(nombre__icontains=request.POST['term'])
```